# How can l change PictureBox when user does not estimate a letter correct?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a hangman game in C#. I've done most of the work. I use dynamic buttons as keyboard. My problem is, that when user clicks on a letter on keyboard that is not present in the word that user should estimate, `picturebox` should replaced with `picturebox2`, and if his estimation is again wrong, replace with `picturebox3`, go on until final `picturebox`. However, if user estimates the letter correctly, picturebox should not replaced. I tried to do this, but my code does not work, as when I click on a button, picturebox keep changing until the last picture even if my estimation is correct or not. where is my mistake?

Here is the part of my code:

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    btn.ForeColor = Color.Red;

    int a = 0;
    // xy is the word that user should estimate
    for (int i = 0; i < xy.Length; i++)
    {
        if (this.Controls.Find("txt" + i, true)[0].Text == btn.Text)
        {
            this.Controls.Find("txt" + i, true)[0].Text = btn.Text;
            this.Controls.Find("txt" + i, true)[0].BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            a++;

            switch(a)
            {
                case 1:
                    pictbx.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/Csharp_Pro/Games/Mine/hangman/hangman/skeleton1.png");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pictbx.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/Csharp_Pro/Games/Mine/hangman/hangman/skeleton2.png");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    pictbx.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/Csharp_Pro/Games/Mine/hangman/hangman/skeleton3.png");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    pictbx.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/Csharp_Pro/Games/Mine/hangman/hangman/skeleton4.png");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    pictbx.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/Csharp_Pro/Games/Mine/hangman/hangman/skeleton5.png");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to count the number of mistakes, you cannot do this correctly with a local variable that starts at 0 every time you click.  Pick a better name than `a`, it must be private field of the class so it retains its value between button clicks.  When you start a new game then reset it back to 0.

Comment: instead of a, l used count as name. l made it public variable but still l do not get why if-else function does not work properly as when a letter match up with button text, picturebox should stay same but it changes. like  when l click button, first check if function, then jump to else, without clicking second time. l m new on c sharp. l did not figure it out.

Comment: is there another way to do what l want without using if-else function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mistake is what Hans mentioned in comments: your variable must be a field of the class and not a local variable on the function, and must reset on each new game.

Second mistake: you check the letter the player clicked against every letter on the word, and for everytime it doesn't match, you add one to your error counter. You must add 1 only after you have finished checking all the letters in your word.

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    btn.ForeColor = Color.Red;

    bool found = false;
    // xy is the word that user should estimate
    for (int i = 0; i < xy.Length; i++)
    {
        if (this.Controls.Find("txt" + i, true)[0].Text == btn.Text)
        {
            this.Controls.Find("txt" + i, true)[0].Text = btn.Text;
            this.Controls.Find("txt" + i, true)[0].BackColor = Color.White;
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        a++;

        switch(a)
        {
            case 1:
                pictbx.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/Csharp_Pro/Games/Mine/hangman/hangman/skeleton1.png");
                break;
            case 2:
                pictbx.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/Csharp_Pro/Games/Mine/hangman/hangman/skeleton2.png");
                break;
            case 3:
                pictbx.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/Csharp_Pro/Games/Mine/hangman/hangman/skeleton3.png");
                break;
            case 4:
                pictbx.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/Csharp_Pro/Games/Mine/hangman/hangman/skeleton4.png");
                break;
            case 5:
                pictbx.Image = Image.FromFile("D:/Csharp_Pro/Games/Mine/hangman/hangman/skeleton5.png");
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

It still has a lot of room for improvement, buy I decided to stop here so you can eventually find it out by yourself while you're learning.

Comment: thanks for answer. l m new and l m trying to learn by practicing. l did not get this part correctly "your variable must be a field of the class and not a local variable on the function, and must reset on each new game" . l need to cover up variable concept better.

Comment: Look up for "variable scope"; that sould cover your doubt. Basically it means that if you declare a variable inside a function, it will only "exist" inside that function, and it will be created and destroyed everytime the function is executed, so its value will be lost. If you declare the variable in the form, it will keep its value as long as the form exists and can be used on every function the form has.